# How can I create a table that only allows data to insert if they are allowed

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can i create a table, that allows only to put data in NAME, if the data matches with the data that i want to be allowed in NAME. So like `Bla1` or `Bla2`.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    NAME VARCHAR(23)
    NAME has to be one of them: ('Bla1', 'Bla2')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  name VARCHAR(23) CHECK( name IN ('Bla1','Bla2') )
);
```

Comment: For the benefit of future seekers: this solution meets the OP's requirement but it is a bad practice and should not be used in anything other than a toy application.

Comment: @APC I do not think so. If you have a fix (neven changing) enumeration you can uses this also in a real application. But if this enumeration is a moving target you should think about other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do it is probably to have a second table with all the allowed names in it, and making a FOREIGN KEY from the name field in your Table1 to the name field in that other table. That'll automatically fail any insert queries for which the name is not contained in the list of allowed names.

This has an advantage over things like ENUM and such in that it does *not* require you to rebuild your table (which is a very expensive operation) every time you want to allow another name and it also allows you to later add additional related info to each name by adding it to the other table.

Here's a great article on why using a foreign key is much better than using enums or other such checks in the table itself: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: Good idea :), but the first method is much easier

Comment: Make sure you check out the article. The first method has a way of coming back to bite you later. (But if this is a small project, that's probably irrelevant and you don't need this solution)

Comment: @Taurus22: the first method quickly becomes messy if the list of values changes constantly.

Comment: Ahh i understand, my project is only a small assignment project (the first solution is needed). But you are right this is the best way to do it.